# How to interpolate and then start again on new day?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, imputation

Following on from my previous question [filling in the missing times using average for the values pythn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71674047/filling-in-the-missing-times-using-average-for-the-values-pythn) , how would I do the same but stop at the end of each day. I have tried grouping but that seems to remove a lot of data.
This is the data I start with:

```
time = np.array([pd.to_datetime("2022-01-01 00:00:00"),pd.to_datetime("2022-01-01 00:00:01"),pd.to_datetime("2022-01-01 00:00:03"), pd.to_datetime("2022-01-01 00:00:04"),pd.to_datetime("2022-01-02 00:00:07"),pd.to_datetime("2022-01-02 00:00:09"), pd.to_datetime("2022-01-02 00:00:10")])
lat = [58.1, 58.4, 58.5, 58.9, 52,52.2, 52.5]
lng = [1.34, 1.44, 1.46, 1.48, 1.35, 1.37, 1.39]

df =  pd.DataFrame({"time": time, "lat": lat, "lng" :lng})


time                lat     lng
2022-01-01 00:00:00 58.1    1.34
2022-01-01 00:00:01 58.4    1.44
2022-01-01 00:00:03 58.5    1.46
2022-01-01 00:00:04 58.9    1.48
2022-01-02 00:00:07 52.0    1.35
2022-01-02 00:00:09 52.2    1.37
2022-01-02 00:00:10 52.5    1.39
```

and the expected output would be:

```
time                lat     lng
2022-01-01 00:00:00 58.1    1.34
2022-01-01 00:00:01 58.4    1.44
2022-01-01 00:00:01 58.45   1.45
2022-01-01 00:00:03 58.5    1.46
2022-01-01 00:00:04 58.9    1.48
2022-01-02 00:00:07 52.0    1.35
2022-01-02 00:00:08 52.1    1.36
2022-01-02 00:00:09 52.2    1.37
2022-01-02 00:00:10 52.5    1.39
```

Using this:

```
df = df.set_index('time').asfreq(freq='S').interpolate()
```

Works perfectly when all my data is from the same day. How would I make it so it resets on the next day?

Comment: If the output should go from `2022-01-01 00:00:00` to `2022-01-01 00:00:04` and `2022-01-02 00:00:07` to `2022-01-02 00:00:10` you can do that with a groupby. But I'm not sure how `05` and `06` can easily be added.

Comment: Sorry removed those rows, had them by accident. How would I do it with the groupBy? 
`df = df.groupBy([df['time'].dt.date)

df = df.set_index('time').asfreq(freq='S').interpolate()`
This doesnt seem to work

Comment: You can use `apply`, I added an answer with the details below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and use a custom function with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to run the relevant interpolation logic:

```
def func(x):
    return x.set_index('time').asfreq(freq='S').interpolate().reset_index()

df.groupby(df['time'].dt.day).apply(func).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
                   time    lat   lng
0   2022-01-01 00:00:00  58.10  1.34
1   2022-01-01 00:00:01  58.40  1.44
2   2022-01-01 00:00:02  58.45  1.45
3   2022-01-01 00:00:03  58.50  1.46
4   2022-01-01 00:00:04  58.90  1.48
5   2022-01-02 00:00:07  52.00  1.35
6   2022-01-02 00:00:08  52.10  1.36
7   2022-01-02 00:00:09  52.20  1.37
8   2022-01-02 00:00:10  52.50  1.39
```